# Minecraft chemistry Update with fish Update

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

So how do you use chemistry inside minecraft? it has confused me help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Chemistry is only available in MineCraft Education edition. This version introduces several new mechanics that can only be accessed on this version. You can read more about the additions here:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chemistry_Update

If you would like to install Education edition, you can do so here:

https://education.minecraft.net/get-started/download/